# does hibernate sql query shown in the cache entities as well

Tags: hibernate, log4j, hibernate-cache

I am printing the sql query in the log by the setting the log level as debug for the hibernate.sql package. there are few queries which are being shown in the logs are from the entity which is using the caching "@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)" on the entity. My question is will the logs show the query even if the entity is cached or it shows the query because the entity is not being cached.

Answer (score -1):

can use this property and add to `hibernate.cfg.xml`, for show all sql query:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my question is different. The logs are already showing the sqls...